# java date of today

Tags: java, sql, date

I am trying to generate the date of today. But I always get: "1969-12-31" as the output.

here my code:

```
java.util.Date d1 = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d1.getDate());
```

I want to add it in a sql table, what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [JavaDocs for `java.util.Date#getDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate--) says *"Returns the day of the month represented by this Date object. The value returned is between 1 and 31 representing the day of the month that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone."*, apart from also been depreciated, this clearly is not the method you want to use

Answer (score 3):

`d1.getDate()` will give an `int` representing the current date. Eg: `23`.

What you need is `d1.getTime()`.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later you should make use of the new java.time framework. These new classes supplant the old classes which have proven so troublesome.

## Time Zone

Note that time zone is crucial in determining a date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( ZoneId );
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `getDate()` function is deprecated.

Try use this:

```java
java.util.Date d1 = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime());
```

Answer (score -1):

java.util.date.getDate documentation says that method is deprecated and time that it is returning is actually a base epoch time which begins from 1970-01-01.Learn more about it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

In order to get the actual date you need to do the following:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```